# Show "All values" in a SelectOneMenu

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, enums, selectonemenu

Showing a JSF page, with a *selectOneMenu* component that lists every item of a *enum* class. This Enum class corresponds to cities.

Problem is that I want to show one field that says "All Cities", as I'm showing a `*List<City>*` I can't add the "All Cities" value because that would be a String.

So actual items being showed in the *SelectOneMenu* is e.g.:

*NYC, San Francisco, Rome, Paris*

And the desired output would be:

*All Cities, NYC, San Francisco, Rome Paris*

Code Example:

Enum:

```
 public enum City {

    ALL, NYC, SANFRANCISCO,...;

    }
```

JSF Page code snippet:

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="citiesmenu" value="#{enumBeanStatus.selectedCity}">
<f:selectItems value="#{enumBean.cities}"/>
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

Comment: You could add the `All Cities` value in your enum. If that's not an option, then you could add `<f:selectItem itemLabel="All Cities" itemValue="#{null}" />` before the `<f:selectItems />`.

Comment: How can I add *All Cities* to my enum, if *All Cities* is not a City :) I would think the second option would be the actual answer :)

Comment: I don't know how you're setting up your enum, but just add `ALL_CITIES` as part as the enum. It could have a different value from the other cities like 0 or another default value, it's just a *trick*.

Comment: @kauedg what kind of code would be useful to solve this problem? It's a logical problem, not a code error.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza add the second comment to the answer so I can select it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how you're setting up your enum, but just add an `ALL_CITIES` as part as the `City` enum. It could have a different value from the other cities like 0 or another default value, it's just a trick. The way how you process the different values is what defines if is a general or a specific one.